# npm start not working because of Webpack mismatch

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I recently copied over a React frontend into the `assets` folder of my Phoenix backend and also added Webpack.

When I run `npm start`, I get this error, even when I remove node modules folder and `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install`, I get the error again when running `npm start`.

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "webpack": "4.19.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/danale/Projects/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.29.0)
```

The error sounds straightforward except that I did a `npm ls webpack` and I am using the version the error says I should be using:

```
└─┬ react-scripts@2.0.5
  └── webpack@4.19.1
```

Please point me in the direction I should be looking.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.2.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.23",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.4.0",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.12",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.9",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.0",
    "jest-dom": "^2.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "phoenix": "^1.3.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-apollo": "^2.3.3",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^9.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.5",
    "react-testing-library": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Comment: And webpack isn't listed as dependency in your package.json?

Comment: @Stramski, no not at all.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Stramski, I added my `package.json` file.

Comment: Do you see any warnings when you run `npm install`?

Comment: @nareddyt, I do see some warnings, but not referencing `react-scripts` or `webpack`

Comment: @nareddyt, I am wondering if its because with CRA we do not need Webpack and no I did not run `npm run eject`.